# How to git pull without overwriting local changes?

Tags: git

I tried pushing some changes I made to my teams repo but received the following error:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "message"
$ git push origin master
! [rejected]  master -> master (fetch first)
```

I then tried doing a fetch (as instructed by the git hint) and received:

```
$ git fetch
$ git push origin master
! [rejected]  master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Now I am being instructed to `git pull` but am afraid my local changes will be overwritten.

After some googling I read that I should do a `git stash` first to protect my local changes but am now receiving:

```
$ git stash
No local changes to save
```

So my question is what should I do next to successfully do a push while not overwriting any of my local changes in the process?

Thanks!

Comment: Now I am thinking I should do a `git merge`. Will that overwrite my local changes?

Comment: `git pull` will not override your local settings. A `git pull` is actually a `git fetch` and a `git merge`. You probably want to stash your changes then pull.

Comment: Ok, so a `git pull` followed by a `git push` was all that was needed. I duplicated all of my local changes as a backup but @EncryptedWatermelon was correct. A `git pull` will not override any local changes. Thanks all :)

Comment: You should never need to duplicate your files if they have been stashed or committed. Commit early and often.

Answer (score 1):

Just do git fetch first it will only get the changes in your origin/branch (you can see them when you do `git branch -a`)
remove the conflicts after merging and then push them to your origin.